# Convert short month names into number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have dates like this and I want to convert those short month names into numbers.

```
Sep 30 2021 19:00:04 +08
```

My desired output is either one of them.

```
2021/30/09 19:00:04 or 20213009190004
```

Comment: Do you have dates?  Dates have no format.  Or do you have strings?  Which do have a format.  My guess is that you have strings since your input appears to have a time zone (I'm guessing that's what "+08" represents) and dates don't have time zones.  But maybe you actually have a timestamp that does have a time zone.  Is your intention to discard the time zone in the output?

Comment: I agree with Justin. We must know whether what you are showing is of type string or timestamp with timezone. Then, you are removing the timezone +08. Is it possible you get datetimes with another timezone? If so, would you simply suppress the timezone, too? Or convert the time to timezone +08 first and only then supress the +08?

Comment: My dates are all string and it doesn't have any other time zone beside +08. So we can just ignore that time zone

Comment: Then it's just one string converted to another. The only issue is the month name. This is probably the English name abbreviated. You can use TO_CHAR, but make sure you are using this with the correct NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE. Or use a custom list of month name abbreviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option

```
SQL> with x ( string ) as ( select 'Sep 30 2021 19:00:04 +08' from dual )
  2  select to_char(to_date(substr(string,0,length(string) - 3),'Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') from x ;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUB
-------------------
2021/09/30 19:00:04

SQL> with x ( string ) as ( select 'Sep 30 2021 19:00:04 +08' from dual )
  2  select to_char(to_date(substr(string,0,length(string) - 3),'Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') from x ;

TO_CHAR(TO_DAT
--------------
20210930190004
```

Comment: Include TO_DATE's third parameter to have NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE match the language used in the string. Otherwise TO_DATE can fail ith an unknown month name.